# redirect in apache2 in ubuntu 18.4

Tags: apache2

I'm a beginner in the Ubuntu.
I hope someone will help me solve this problem.
Use Ubuntu and Apache2.

As in many websites, for example, when you are prompted for your username and
password you will be redirected to https page and after you finish you
get returned back to plain http as follows.
http://localhost/login redirected to https://localhost/login and when you
submit the form you redirected back to http://localhost/index.html

Any one can help me please?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Please show us enough to work with.

Comment: P.S. only allow https on your site.